Determining if a quadratic map is a strange attractor using Lyapunov exponent
I stumbled across an interesting paper from decades ago, about a simple way to find strange attractors of the following quadratic map:
$$
x_{n+1}=a_1+a_2x_n+a_3x_n^2+a_4x_ny_n+a_5y_n+a_6y_n^2\\
y_{n+1}=a_7+a_8x_n+a_9x_n^2+a_{10}x_ny_n+a_{11}y_n+a_{12}y_n^2.
$$
The coefficients $a_i$ are fixed.
I can intuitively understand that if a strange attractor exists for given coefficients $a_i$, there is a "basin of attraction" - an initial point inside this basin should remain in this basin after repeatedly evaluating the map.
Now, chaotic behavior could exist without the map being an attractor. As the paper explains, one can use the Lyapunov exponent to help determine this. At a high level, if two points initially 'close together' end up diverging farther and farther, we could take that as evidence that the map is not an attractor. The Lyapunov exponent, as I understand it, is a formalization of this idea of divergence.
The paper chooses an initial point $(0.05, 0.05)$ for iterating the map. To calculate the Lyapunov exponent the paper uses a second point $(0.05+10^{-6},0.05)$.
What I don't understand is what the author is doing here:

In particular, how is the author calculating two exponents? I only see one formula for $L$, and I'm assuming the $d_n$ is simply the Euclidean distance, i.e.
$$
d_n=\sqrt{(Y-Y')^2+(X-X')^2},
$$
for $(X,Y)=f^n(0.05,0.05)$ and $(X',Y')=f^n(0.05+10^{-6},0.05)$, with $f$ the quadratic map described above.
And moreover, what exactly is the proposed "remedy" of "after each iteration the points are moved back to their original separation along the direction of separation"?
I should add that I have only the most cursory understanding of this topic. I'm engaging with these concepts on a recreational level, but I'd love to learn a little more. I want to implement in code for myself what the paper does, but the code/algorithm given in the paper's appendix is written in BASIC, which I'm not familiar with.

The number of Lyapunov exponents is equal to the number of dimensions of the phase space. The two exponents could represent the divergence of both directions in the phase space.
